# Application.StartupPath is changed after app is added to msconfig startup

Tags: c#, windows

and thank you for taking your time to help me.

I have an app that I'm adding to startup in registry with the code:

```
RegistryKey setRunAtStartup = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey  ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        setRunAtStartup.SetValue("mls", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

And I also have a ini.xml file that needs to be in the same folder as my app. So I access it in this manner:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "/ini.xml");
```

The problem is, after rebooting computer Application.StartupPath is no longer returning my old path but returns C:\Windows\System32\myapp.exe, thus it throws an exception: cannot find the needed ini.xml in that folder.
How can I fix this? I need a method that will return REAL path in order to access my ini.xml. Thank you!

Comment: Your diagnostic certainly doesn't match the way this normally works.  Application.StartupPath doesn't change, it is still where ever you copied the EXE file.  You could only get c:\windows\system32 if you copied it there.  At least document what you see with Regedit.exe when you look at the Run key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the current working directory. Instead use:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

like so:

```
Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    "myIniFile.ini")
```

Comment: this: Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath); on form_load() solved my problem. Thank you anyway!